# /bin/bash: line 89: docker: command not found GITLAB CI/CD ISSUE

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to push my code on Gitlab using Gitlab CI/CD but it constantly fails on the push stage giving me the below error. 
Any ideas as to what's causing this?

Issue taken from the push stage:

```
1 Running with gitlab-runner 12.6.0-rc1 (ec299e72)
2   on docker-auto-scale 72989761
3
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.5 ...
00:36
4 Pulling docker image ruby:2.5 ...
5 Using docker image sha256:54cb86b0bcdc353e103e9dd1bff69fcd01e3235420ed17cbf5efac22010b373e for ruby:2.5 ...
7
Running on runner-72989761-project-16138356-concurrent-0 via runner-72989761-srm-1578059087-b5d7ed4b...
00:05
9
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
00:01
10 Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
11 Initialized empty Git repository
12 Created fresh repository.
14  * [new ref]         refs/pipelines/106842100 -> refs/pipelines/106842100
15  * [new branch]      master                   -> origin/master
16 Checking out 54a35cd8 as master...
17 Skipping Git submodules setup
21
$ docker login -u "gitlab-ci-token" -p "$CI_BUILD_TOKEN" "$CI_REGISTRY"
00:01
22 /bin/bash: line 89: docker: command not found
26 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: SOLVED: I managed to solve the issue which was caused by the fact that shared runners were activated (hence ruby was used instead of a shell executor which I chose during the setup) - deactivating of the shared runners fixed the issue.

Comment: (That is a comment, not an answer @monixm )

Answer (score 1):

You're using a ruby image that either doesn't have docker or has it installed somewhere not in `$PATH`.

If it does not have docker, install it via `apt-get install docker`.

If it has, append docker path via `export PATH=$PATH:<docker_path>`.

Comment: thanks for your help. I managed to solve the issue which was caused by the fact that shared runners were activated (hence ruby was used instead of a shell executor which I chose during the setup) - deactivating of the shared runners fixed the issue.

Comment: You must answer your own question then, for people to be aware of how this was solved.